# RegEx - Match all MAC addresses except for 00:00:00:00:00:00

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with multiple MAC addresses.  How do I match all MACs except 00:00:00:00:00:00?

The regex I use to match a MAC:

```
((?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2})
```

Comment: Why can't you just do it with a second regex ?

Comment: Do you need a regex for comparing an exact value? How about where regex.Match(strInput) && strInput != "00:00:00:00:00:00"?

Comment: using conditionals with 2 regexes is probably less computationally-intensive than one big regex that will need to get evaluated for each case

Comment: @john I thought about that (in my case it would look more like `foreach (Group group in matches.Groups) { if (group.Value != "00:00:00:00:00:00") DoWork(); }`

Since I have my regex in the AppSettings, I was hoping to just change that instead of modifying code and redeploying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly I'd recommend doing it in two parts. First fetch all the individual addresses using your regex, and then simply remove any zeroed addresses from the list. This is...

1. Most likely less computationally expensive, and
2. Far easier to read and maintain than a massive kludge of a regular expression.

Comment: Or you can have a two-part regex.  The first part only matching zero MAC's.  You can then have two captures.  If the MAC is all-zero, the first capture will have stuff in it.  If it is not all-zero, the first capture will be empty and the second capture will have stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern you would need to do that:

`(?!(?:00[:-]){5}00)((?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2})`

**Edit** - an answer to @trev's "how could you do this?"

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @samps = (
 'MATCH_ME mac1=11:22:33:44:55:66 mac2=00:11:22:33:44:55',
 'MATCH_ME mac1=00:00:00:00:00:00 mac2=00:11:22:33:44:55',
 'MATCH_ME mac1=11:22:33:44:55:66 mac2=00:00:00:00:00:00',
 'MATCH_ME mac1=00:00:00:00:00:00 mac2=00:00:00:00:00:00',
);

for (@samps) {

   if ( /(MATCH_ME)\s*
           mac1=
              (   (?!(?:00[:-]){5}00)
                  (?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2}
                |
              )
              .*?
           mac2=
              (   (?!(?:00[:-]){5}00)
                  (?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2}
                |
              )
        /x )
   {
     print "'$1'\n";
     print "'$2'\n";
     print "'$3'\n",'-'x20,"\n";
   }
}
```

output

`'MATCH_ME'`
`'11:22:33:44:55:66'`
`'00:11:22:33:44:55'`
`--------------------`
`'MATCH_ME'`
`''`
`'00:11:22:33:44:55'`
`--------------------`
`'MATCH_ME'`
`'11:22:33:44:55:66'`
`''`
`--------------------`
`'MATCH_ME'`
`''`
`''`

Comment: nice!  Now how would I use that to return "MATCH_ME" and both the MACs in this (keeping in mind that either could be the zero-mac): 

`MATCH_ME mac1=11:22:33:44:55:66 mac2=00:11:22:33:44:55`

Comment: @Trev this is just programming left as an excercise. This is the answer to how `(MATCH_ME)\s*mac1=((?!(?:00[:-]){5}00)(?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2}|).*mac2=((?!(?:00[:-]){5}00)(?:[0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}[0-9a-f]{2}|)` But I would format it to make it readable like my example above.